# Regex to extract the date based on particular string

Tags: python, regex, python-re

am trying to extract the date if it matches to a particular regex

Ex :

```
string1 = '10/22/2019 from'
string2 = '12/22/2020 33455SE'
string3 = '7/20/2020 S0023'
```

Am trying to extract the string 2

Regex used :

```
r'(\d+[/]\d+[/]\d+[-\s\.]\d+)'
```

The above used regex is giving me if the string looks like, `"10/22/2019 33455"` but if there is a alphabet after as shown `"33455SE"`, my code fails.

Any help ?

Tried codes :

```
r'(\d+[/]\d+[/]\d+[-\s\.]^\d+)' - Tried to use starts with.
```

Expected output : only string 2 and string 3

```
12/22/2020
7/20/2020
```

Comment: Do you want to say `33455SE` is a date? What are your requirements?

Comment: updated my question, please check the expected output.

Comment: Use `^(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew will this not give me both the dates ?

Comment: And have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have tried it, it gives me all the dates, please re open the qusestion

Comment: [**It works well**](https://ideone.com/GSP6UD). You must not have tried it correctly.

Comment: Exacly, so you havent read my question and closed it.  Can you please check my expected output ?

Comment: No idea what you mean by your edit. What do you mean by only 2 and 3? What is wrong with `10/22/2019 from`? Why is no match expected?

Comment: Right now, the question sounds like "extract a dd/mm/yyyy` date like string from a string". Please edit the question to specify the exact requirements.

Comment: That means, I done need this `10/22/2019 from` particular format .. I need only string 2 and string 3 dates ...

Comment: My question is extract a date based on particular string ...

Comment: "I don't need this" - why?, "based on particular string" - what string?

Comment: As it doesnt have a digit in it... thats my criteria

Comment: `from` doesnt have a digit in it, hence I dont want that date.

Comment: `re.search(r'\b\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\b(?!\s*[^\W\d]+\b)', text)`? https://ideone.com/t6oPAK

Comment: cool, now you got me. Thanks for it @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score -1):

This works

```
import re
a = "3443E hello 10/22/2019 33455SE"
number = re.findall(r"[0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{4}",a)
print(number[0])
```

Output :

```
10/22/2019
```

Comment: Please check my updated question and the expected output

Answer (score -2):

This should work:

```
r'(\d+[/]\d+[/]\d+[-\s\.]\d+[A-Z]*)'
```

Comment: please check my updated question and expected output

Answer (score -2):

```
\d{1,2}/\d{2}/\d{4}(?=\s\w*\d+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/gCXHQ6/3